# Filemaker: Getting file input in a form (filemaker pro 6)

Tags: filemaker

How can I create a filemaker form where the user enters some personal details and has to choose multiple files to upload?

I want it to be an equivalent to `<input type="file">` in a html form.

Is it possible using filemaker pro 6?

Comment: Do the users have a fixed number of files to upload?

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by "an equivalent to in a html form." your form can look how ever you want it too look you design the look in layout mode but your not gonna write html to create a form in filemaker if thats what you mean.

not sure if you can do it in filemaker 6 but try this

1. create a field in your table called "attachments" and make its type a container
2. create a script from the script menu call it insert picture
   3 add these script steps [image]

let me know if that does what you want

Comment: No no... I meant, I want it to be equivalent to **'<input type="file">'** in html. I wonder why that was removed from my question.

Comment: Yes, it kinda does what I want. But, I want to let the user select multiple files... this way you can only select one file... I think I can play around with the script, do some looping and try a work around... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use container fields, which store files. In FM 6 they lacked a lot of the features they have currently, and they had a clunky interface, but it works.

Be careful though; you might run into the 2GB/file FM6 limit (which went away in 7) after a while.

Answer (score 0):

This would be possible, including multi-file selection, in FM7+ with an addition of a plugin, ScriptMaster plugin can be used to display a FileChooser that allows multi-file selection.

I'm not aware of any plugins that can do this in FM6, but take a look at [24U SimpleDialog](http://www.24usoftware.com/simpledialog) at least it's FM6 compatible.